# How to run a function after wp() in the wp-blog-header.php file?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I want to run a function after the `wp();` line in the file `wp-blog-header.php`, what is the proper `hook` to use here?

```php
<?php
/**
 * Loads the WordPress environment and template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

    $wp_did_header = true;

    // Load the WordPress library.
    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

    // Set up the WordPress query.
    wp();

    /********************************************
       I WANT TO RUN THE FUNCTION AT THIS POINT 
     ********************************************/

    // Load the theme template.
    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );

}
```

#### Why do I need the hook

We are migrating to a new website and we have to care about the old URLs, so what I did:

1. Added the following `rewrite` rule to our `NGINX` config file:

`rewrite \D+(\/\d+\/\D+)$ /index.php?redirect=$1 break;`

This rule will add an extra parameter `redirect` to the URL (old URL) with a value that I will be using to get the new final URL.

2. Then I will run the following code to get this value from the incoming URL and get the final URL by querying a 2-columns table that maps each value `redirect_from` with a final URL `redirect_to`:

```php
/**
 * 1. Check if the URL has a parameter [redirect]
 * 2. If NO, proceed to the next step
 * 3. If YES, then get that parameter value and look into [redirects] table
 * 4. If you found a row that has that value, then get the [redirect_to] value
 * 5. Redirect to that URL [redirect_to]
 */

if (isset($_GET['redirect'])) {
    // Get the parameter value from the URL
    $redirect_from = $_GET['redirect'];
    // Add the table prefix to the table name
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'redirects';
    // The SQL query
    $query = "
        SELECT redirect_to
        FROM $table_name
        WHERE redirect_from = '$redirect_from';
    ";
    // Run the SQL query and get the results
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);

    // If there was a result then do the redirection and exit
    if (wp_redirect($result[0]->redirect_to)) {exit;}
}
```

**Note:**
No way to get the new URLs from old URLs, here is an example of the old and new URLs:

Redirect from:

`http://www.example.com/category/sub-category/post-id/slug`

to:

`https://www.example.com/category/sub-category/yyyy/mm/dd/slug`

Comment: If you explained why you wanted to do this we might be able to provide some actual suggestions.

Comment: Thank you @cabrerahector , I've already updated the question, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you looked into `Redirection` plugin which does exactly this? You can configure all the redirects on an individual level or with patterns that dynamically match certain situations, as well as 404 logs so you can see where other redirects may be needed. https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/